# angular form is always returning false/invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form where I am checking if the form is invalid if yes it should just stop the application and if not do something else. But right now my form is always returning invalid = true and I can not find the error for some reason. Could someone look and tell me whats wrong

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input 
        formControlName="personNameField"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Bitte eingeben"
        [ngClass]="{'error': personNameField.errors}"
        ></input>
</form>
```

ts files with formcontrol:

```
    form = this.builder.group({
    personNameField: new FormControl('',
      [Validators.required]),
  });
```

method to check if form is valid/invalid:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Required validation is validation your field so if you want to add error only when if form touched then you can add this.form.touched along with form.controls.personNameField.errors

Comment: I want the validation to be invalid when the field is empty, but in this case even if i put a value inside and type something it is still seen as invalid. I do not know why tbh

Answer (score 0):

1. you added the `Validators.required` validator, this means you have to enter a text in your `input` otherwise the form is invalid.
2. if this is not the error, please create an example on stackblitz and share the link

Answer (score 0):

I have just copy-pasted your code and it is working fine for me.

Here is working code : [https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2wmgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone who helped me out. The error was a formcontrol not being rendered thus I could never enter a value so it was invalid